# How can I remove the last semicolon in a string?

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I'm working with many strings like with this structure:

```
=Cluster=
SPEC    PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22493.xml;spectrum=4691 true    LHDEEIQELQAQIQEQHVQIDMDVSKPDLTAALR  3940.8833   1   9913        0.9988012901749596
SPEC    PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22495.xml;spectrum=752  true    LHDEEIQELQAQIQEQHVQIDMDVSKPDLTAALR  3940.8833   1   9913        0.9988012901749596
```

Due to a bug in the program that generate the files, sometimes extra semicolons appear where should be just one, and appear where they should not appear. 
For example:

```
=Cluster=
SPEC    PRD000681;;;;;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22493.xml;spectrum=4691 true    LHDEEIQELQAQIQEQHVQIDMDVSKPDLTAALR  3940.8833   1    9913   ;   0.9988012901749596
SPEC    PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22495.xml;;;;spectrum=752   true    LHDEEIQELQAQIQEQHVQIDMDVSKPDLTAALR  3940.8833   1    9913   ;   0.9988012901749596
```

In order to fix this I am using regular expression `s/;+/;/g;` or `awk '{gsub(/[;]+/,";")}1'input > output` but I have no idea how I remove remove the last semicolon without affecting the first ones.

One good output would be something like this:

```
=Cluster=
SPEC    PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22493.xml;spectrum=4691 true    LHDEEIQELQAQIQEQHVQIDMDVSKPDLTAALR  3940.8833   1   9913        0.9988012901749596
SPEC    PRD000681;PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_22495.xml;spectrum=752  true    LHDEEIQELQAQIQEQHVQIDMDVSKPDLTAALR  3940.8833   1   9913        0.9988012901749596
```

My question is: How could I remove the last semicolon without affecting the first semicolons?

Comment: Stating the obvious here, but the best option, if at all possible, is to fix the program that generates the bad data.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes, the bug was fixed but these files are from 2014.  The files from 2017 haven't got this problem.

Comment: @Enrique: Is this pattern fixed always, i,e. column 2 has those multiple `;` and column at 8 has a `;` or it can vary

Comment: @Inian the main problem is with the last `;`, because it should not be there. I use the `,` of colum 2 to split the data with another application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [How do I replace the last occurrence of a character in a string using sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187894/40596) you can say:

```
sed -r 's/(.*);/\1/' file
```

That is, match everything with `.*` until the last `;` is found. This works because sed is very greedy and will slurp everything until the last `;` is found.

Together with your initial expression, you will have:

```
sed -re 's/;+/;/g' -e 's/(.*);/\1/' file
```

---

Since your input file has so much data, it is hard to see the output. See it live with some dummy data:

```
$ cat file
hello;;;;;how;are;you
i;am;fine
```

Just remove the last semi colon:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*);/\1/' file
hello;;;;;how;areyou
i;amfine
```

Remove the last semi colon and squeeze multiple semi colons:

```
$ sed -re 's/;+/;/g' -e 's/(.*);/\1/' file
hello;how;areyou
i;amfine
```

Comment: Just in plain _awe_, how quickly you can pull things out of the air. Great stuff!

Answer (score 3):

In Perl

```
perl -i -pe 's/.*\K;//' myfile
```

Comment: Nice one, but I think he's lookin for `s/.*\K;//;s/;+/;/g`

Comment: @klashxx: Sure. I was just answering the specific question *"How could I remove the last semicolon?"*. I think I'd prefer `s/;\K;+//g` to avoid replacing single semicolons, but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @Borodin or y/;//s

Comment: @ysth: Goodness. That's a corner of Perl that I had completely forgotten. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rev` and awk (and @fedorqui's example):

```
$ rev file | awk '{ sub(/;/, "") }1' | rev
hello;;;;;how;areyou
i;amfine
```

Use `rev` to reverse the records, delete the first `;` with `sub` instead and `rev` the records again. You can use `gsub` first to replace multiple `;`s with one:

```
$ rev file | awk '{ gsub(/\;+/, ";"); sub(/;/, "") }1' | rev
hello;how;areyou
i;amfine
```